# Installing MapFish print issues

Tags: python, python-2.7, mapfish

I am trying to install Mapfish print in my windows 7,i followed this [document](http://www.mapfish.org/doc/2.2/installation.html)

When it try to run this line `python.exe go-mapfish-framework-2.2.py --no-site-packages env` I got this message in my cmd :

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "go-mapfish-framework-2.2.py", line 2055, in 
>       main()   File "go-mapfish-framework-2.2.py", line 797, in main
>       never_download=options.never_download)   File "go-mapfish-framework-2.2.py", line 897, in create_environment
>       search_dirs=search_dirs, never_download=never_download)   File "go-mapfish-framework-2.2.py", line 590, in install_setuptools
>       search_dirs=search_dirs, never_download=never_download)   File "go-mapfish-framework-2.2.py", line 564, in _install_req
>       cwd=cwd)   File "go-mapfish-framework-2.2.py", line 865, in call_subprocess
>       % (cmd_desc, proc.returncode)) OSError: Command c:\Python27\env\Scripts\python.exe -c "#!python
>   \"\"\"Bootstra...sys.argv[1:]) " --always-copy -U setuptools failed
>   with error code 1

I don't know what is wrong,can anyone help me?

Comment: please post the solution if u solved it